# How do I set the spelling dictionary in Git Gui?

Tags: git, git-gui

In the options for [Git Gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui), there is a section to select a spelling. However, no dictionary options actually show up in the selection menu. How do I configure the spell checker in Git Gui?

[image: Git GUI Dictionary Option]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source: [Configure Git Gui spell checker on Windows](https://tarasalenin.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/configure-git-gui-spell-checker-on-windows/)

> Follow these step to configure interactive spell checker for [msysGit](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) GIT GUI:
>
> 1. Download and install [Aspell](http://aspell.net/win32/). Also download and install any dictionaries you may need.
> 2. Add the Aspell binaries folder (a folder where the installer places aspell.exe) to the PATH environment variable. For more information on
>    how to do this have a look at [How to set the path and environment
>    variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).
> 3. If you had GIT GUI open, re-start it and open options (Edit -> Options…).
> 4. Pick a dictionary to use from “Spelling Dictionary” drop down list (this time it should have more choices available).